# C++11 regex multiline: Why does the group ([^\\0]+\n)?some_text have everything in match[1]?

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio-2010, c++11

I'm trying to understand regular expressions better. I'm using Visual Studio 2010. Take for example this expression. In Visual Studio 2010 you can't skip over newlines with `[\s\S]` so I've heard it's ok to use `[^\0]`. In the expression I want to match a line but only if it is `line 3`.

```
if(regex_search("line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n",
    match,
    regex("^([^\\0]+\\n)?line (3)\\n")))
{
    cout << "match.length(): " << match.length() << endl;

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < match.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << "match[" << i <<"]: \"" << match[i] << "\"" << endl;
    }
}
```

**Please note the above code won't work with gcc < 4.9 or ideone (since it uses gcc < 4.9).**

In Visual Studio 2010 the code returns:

```
match.length(): 21
match[0]: "line 1
line 2
line 3
"
match[1]: "line 1
line 2
line 3
"
match[2]: "3"
```

I'm sure there are better ways to match lines but my question is just why did match[1] group match the whole input? I figured the regex would read `line 1\nline 2\n` for match[1] and stop since I have `line 3` after it in the regex. Is there a word for it in regular expressions or is it a bug?

Thanks and if you have edit powers you're welcome to edit this so it's easier to understand.

Comment: FYI, you can try and tweak your regex here: http://regexhero.net/tester/ It's for the .Net framework, but I think that would work for you.

Comment: @Joce Pretty cool. It gives the results I expected: match[1] is "line 1\nline 2\n" http://i.imgur.com/OXmpjIX.png I'm not sure why it's different in Visual Studio.

Comment: Posting a (minimal) *complete* example would help, because then I could just copy 'n' paste it into clang++. I'm not 100% sure if what I've filled in and put into clang exactly matches the code you're not showing, but clang says "The expression contained an invalid escaped character, or a trailing escape." Changing it to `[\s\S]` for clang gives the expected results. I suspect this is a VS 2010 bug (remember, C++11 hadn't even been finalized by the time VS 2010 was released, so VS 2010's support of C++11 was still experimental).

Comment: @Cornstalks The example was almost complete.. that's all the code I have in main(). I agree it's probably a bug so I have submitted my own answer. I don't know why it says invalid escape in clang.. since it's a string literal in C++ I have each backslash escaped with a backslash and maybe that had something to do with it? I think the regex is valid since I've since tried it in some other places and it worked as I expected. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the `match[1]` result I get in Visual Studio 2010 is due to a bug.

In Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 and gcc 4.9.0 (20140405) the code returns what I expect:

```
match.length(): 21
match[0]: "line 1
line 2
line 3
"
match[1]: "line 1
line 2
"
match[2]: "3"
```

Online regular expression testers [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/) and [Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/tester/) show the same thing.

In Visual Studio 2010 to make the expression work properly I can make it "lazy" by adding a question mark after the plus sign: `"^([^\\0]+?\\n)?line (3)\\n"`. (That's a string literal so each backslash is escaped with a backslash.) Although it works now (but differently since it's now finding the closest match since it's lazy) I'm sure it's better to just use the latest Visual Studio.

[clang-503.0.40 has a different but related bug](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19678) where it can't process "[^\0]*".

Answer (score 1):

For the record, this works in Visual Studio and finds the third line, returning "line 3: :

`^(?<=(?:[^\n]+\n){2})[^\n]+`

As for your expression,

```
^([^\0]+\n)?line (3)\n
```

We have to decide if you are trying to match in **Visual Studio's Find function** or by making a console program in **Visual Studio**. These are two very different cases.

**A. In Visual Studio's Find Function**

In Visual Studio's Find function, if you make a text file like this:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

your regex will not match. Why? Because after `line 3` you cannot find `\n` in a Visual Studio file. Instead, at the line break, you find `\r\n` which is the standard Windows line break.

Adding the `\r` fixes it:

```
^([^\0]+\n)?line (3)\r\n
```

That being said, this regex matches **any line**, not just line 3, for the simple reason that the `[^\0]` eats up all the characters, including the newlines, then backtracks until it is before the final new line, at which stage the `\n`, `line 3` and `\n` tokens complete the match. If you wanted to use [^\0] instead of [^\n], this would be sure you match line 3:

```
^(?<=([^\0]+?\n){2})line 3\r\n
```

**B. In a Console App built in Visual Studio**

If you feed a console app your string `"line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n"`, then your original regex matches. However, it matches all three lines, for the reason mentioned above (the `[^\0]` eats up all the characters, including the newlines, then backtracks until it is before the final new line, at which stage the `\n`, `line 3` and `\n` tokens complete the match).

Here, if you only want line 3 and use `[^\0]`, you can use this for instance:

```
^(?<=([^\0]+?\n){2})line 3\n
```

Comment: Thanks for your message. I think the regex buddy you posted is wrong? because I have to escape backslashes in string literals. Without those escapes it looks like `^([^\0]+\n)?line (3)\n`

Comment: @test Thanks for pointing this out. Please see my revised explanation of what is happening with \0.

Comment: @Cornstalks You're right, non-null is exactly what I meant, a I'm sure the regex below to match actual NULL bytes shows. That's a typo. Fixing it now, thank you.

Comment: @test @Cornstalks I finally got to the bottom of it! It had to do with `\r` Please see full explanation in my revised answer.

Comment: @zx81, which version of Visual Studio are you using?  Your regex will work in VS2013, but VS2010 still uses that [bizarre regex flavor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) it originally shipped with.

Comment: @AlanMoore Ha, you are right, it is VS2013. Great catch. :)

Comment: @zx81 It's for a console app. Does the find function use C++ as well? Anyway thanks for the info but I cannot mark your answer as correct. Visual Studio 2012, 2013 and two online regex testers all show `line 1\nline 2\n` which is what I expect for `match[1]` so I suspect it's a bug in Visual Studio 2010. I can do a lazy expression as a workaround. I have submitted my own answer which I will mark as correct tomorrow.

Comment: @test My tests are as reported (both in VS2013 and as console apps, but C# not C++). Although I believe my explanation of the regex is helpful and correct, in the end your answer that "it's a bug in VS2010" directly answers the question, so upvoting you for that. :)